# How to combine two Set in Spark Data frame in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am Creating a set column in a Dataframe using collect_set using groupBy function in spark scala.

like below...

```
val ERROR_GEN_DF1 = GEN_DF.groupBy("KEY_COL").agg(collect_set("ERROR_DESCRIPTION").alias("ERROR_DESCRIPTION_TEMP_GEN"),collect_set("ERROR_COLUMN").alias("ERROR_COLUMN_TEMP_GEN")).drop("ERROR_DESCRIPTION","ERROR_COLUMN")


val ERROR_PROD_DF1 = ERROR_GEN_DF1.groupBy("KEY_COL2").agg(collect_set("ERROR_DESCRIPTION").alias("ERROR_DESCRIPTION_TEMP_PROD"),collect_set("ERROR_COLUMN").alias("ERROR_COLUMN_TEMP_PROD")).drop("ERROR_DESCRIPTION","ERROR_COLUMN")
```

I need to create a new Dataframe to create a new column by combining the above two set of respective dataframe.

Like `val New_DF = ERROR_GEN_DF1.withColumn("NewSet",<ERROR_DESCRIPTION_TEMP_PROD + ERROR_DESCRIPTION_TEMP_GEN>)`

Please advice what functions to combine or merge two set column in spark dataframe

Thanks,
Naveen

Comment: `array_union` / `concat`, depending on whether you want to keep duplicates

Comment: set will not allow duplicates right.... so which one will be better??

Comment: Hi mck, I am not able to use array_union even though i imported below API..
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
please suggest

Comment: requires spark >= 2.4